Get time of Current+1 Candle's closing time
if N is the current active candle of a timeframe "tf", is there any way to get the closing time of [N+1] candle ?
[N+1] opening time can be obtained via time_close(tf), but how does one obtains its closing time ? or is it simply not possible ?
i have tried using time_close(tf) + (time_close(tf) - time(tf)), while its the best solution i can come up with, some lines are not drawn properly, i think there must be some issue with this which im not comprehending, anyways just wanted to ask if anyone else has a more cleaner solution.

In what cases it doesn't work?
